Can I stop the Linux 'less' command invoked with mutliple filenames from clearing the screen between files?
When I invoke Linux less with multiple filenames, less -X file1 file2 file3, it clears the screen when it goes from one file to the next. I'm using -X to stop "less" from clearing the screen when it exits and this works - the screen is not cleared at the end. I can't seem to find any option to stop less from clearing the screen between files. Is there a way to do this?
I haven't tried anything else because I can't find an option to try.
--- Additional description ---
To address the comments to this question, let me clarify. The most succinct statement is: I want it to be like the original more command. I've know you can set the MOREISLESS environment variable to get less to act, as much as possible, like more but that doesn't help with the issue I'm raising here.
Basically, the original more didn't every clear the screen, it scrolled putting a header with the filename when it started a new file. It did stop at the end of a page full of text from the current file and prompt the user to go to the next page.

Wait, what? If -X works and doesn’t clear the screen what exactly is your question?

Do you mean you want to see all files toghether? Such as in cat file1 file file3 | less?

You mean that if a file has say only 5 lines, then you also want to see the other - say 20 lines from the preceding file, as well as the file with only 5? Then the answer by default is no, but you are quite at liberty to hack on the source to enable it.

I added some additional details to my description above which I hope will help, :-). I agree that I can try to modify the "less" source to try and get what I want and I may do that. But before I did, I wanted to see if it was already possible. Thanks to everyone.

This and then like TERM=tmux256-noalt less …. An alias alias less='TERM=tmux256-noalt less' may be useful.

Bear with me, what distro are you on? Can't you just use more? more on my Ubuntu box seems to do exactly that, unless I'm missing something. If I pass it more than one filename, it will print a header for each file and prompt me to go to the next page.

I appreciate all the comments and answer! I was mostly asking if "less" could mimic "more" (in the ways I described) with enough flags, :-). It looks like that isn't an option.This has come up on a Mac laptop not in a Linux environment.

(sorry) I got cut off while completing my last comment. In the Mac environment, "more" is hard linked to "less" (same inode). I haven't been able to find any source for "more". It's not important enough for me to write something but I appreciate Hannu providing the answer below.

Include this is in either of .bashrc or .bash_aliases in your $HOME
function catt {
if [ "$#" -le "0" ] ;then
  echo "bash: will act as basic cat, but prepends filename as title row for each file"
else
  while [ "$#" -gt "0" ] ;do
    echo -e "\e[7;1m////===--- $1 ---===///\e[K\e[m"
    cat "$1"
    echo ""
    shift
  done
fi
}

... it will create a catt 'command' that can be used fairly equally to cat; the only intended difference being the display of the actual filename before the content of the file.
This makes it possible to display e.g. a number of files in a single go. Maybe most useful with a set of short files.
Now, this also means that they form a single stream of characters, i.e. less will show them "on a single page" - i.e without clearing between files.
To have the title (filename) row be visible in the best manner you need to add the -R option to less as in...
$ catt file1 file2 file3 | less -R 
Or, for a working example; to check content of /bin/ folder files of size less than 150.
$ catt $(find "/bin/" -size -150c -a  -type f) | less -R

Thank you for the ideas and code!

You might benefit from understanding Super User in basic ways - check https://superuser.com/tour
